# SSH from OpenSSH 9 to OpenSSH 5 protocol 2 fails: “illegal argument”

Tags: ssh, openssh, scp, openssl, vmware

I'm trying to connect from a VMware ESXi 8 machine
to a VMware ESXi 5 machine to transfer all the virtual machines. 
The problem is that ssh doesn't connect. 
The old machine has OpenSSH 5 and the new machine has OpenSSH 9.

When I connect from my computer to the old machine, I use the:

```
ssh -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss -o ServerAliveInterval=30 user@machine
```

to allow connections with that obsolete algorithm. 
However, if I try that from the ESXi 8,
it doesn't work, saying “illegal argument”:

```
[root@s02:~] ssh -vvv -oHostkeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss user@machine
OpenSSH_9.0p1, OpenSSL 3.0.7 1 Nov 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data //.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname *.*.*.* is address
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to *.*.*.* [*.*.*.*] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x48
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.0
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.6
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_5.6 pat OpenSSH_5* compat 0x0c000002
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to *.*.*.*:22 as 'root'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: no algorithms matched; accept original
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-dss
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-dss
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 34
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(2048<7680<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP received
ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to *.*.*.* port 22: invalid argument
```

Tried also with

```
ssh -vvv -oHostkeyAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa user@machine
```

But the problem is the same, always illegal argument.

Comment: It's obviously something about the received (selected by old server) DH group, but I don't see any obvious candidates that would give this error. If you can get a capture to look at that would be nice. Otherwise, try forcing a fixed (unselected) group, with the only decent offer being `[-o]KexAlgorithm=diffie-hellman-group14-sha1`